# How to find the charging time of a capacitor given a frequency and an amplitude

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, frequency, amplitude

[image]

In the circuit above, suppose the input pulse signal has an amplitude of 1V and a frequency of 1 kHz. The resistance is 56 kilo-ohms and the capacitance is 1 nF. So if I want to find the charging time, should I simply find the time constant (R*C) and then multiply it by 5 (because it takes a 5 time constants to fully charge a capacitor)? Or will the frequency and amplitude come into play?

Answer (score 5):

It won't "charge".
At 1 KHz, the voltage at the output will follow the input but with a small phase difference and small attenuation.
The capacitor plays little or no role at that frequency and with that resistor.

Beware that this changes totally if you would have e.g. a 2.84MHz. signal.

[image]

Sorry, with pulse I was assuming a sine wave which was switch on at T=0.
Added 1KHz, 50% duty cycle square picture. The capacitor charges but 'un-charges' as quickly.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Five time constants gets you nearly all the way: -

[image]

So if your input voltage is 10 volts, 5xRC gets you to about 99% or 9.9 volts. If your input voltage is 1 volts then you get to 0.99 volts in 5xRC. Frequency can only cut the process short if too high.

56 kohm and 1 nF have a time constant of 56 us hence 5 x 56 us is 280 us. If your frequency is 1 kHz (charge period of 500 us and off period of 500 us) you will get to within nearly 9xRC time constants.

Comment: Can you please explain the relationship between frequency and charging time? Is there some formula that I need to apply?

Comment: There is no relationship mathematically until the frequency reaches a point where the desired minimum charge time is cut short by the input frequency causing charging to turn to discharging.

Comment: As frequency is 1/time there is a relation but it is rather complex. As @Andy aka says: it only becomes noticable if the frequency (1/time) gets shorter then e.g. the 90-95% charging time. For capacitor charging time look at wiki under 'capacitor' or 'RC circuit'.

Comment: I just did a simulation of this circuit in the QUCS simulator. It seems that the time it takes for the capacitor voltage to reach the max voltage (1V) is around 0.00042 seconds. Any idea how this was derived?

Comment: The thing is I'm supposed to find the charging time of the above capacitor by calculation for an assignment. So there has to be another way to do this

Comment: Then you are misreading or misrepresenting the asignment OR your tutor has misdirected you OR you are not coming clean with the full story here. Either way, the laws of physics are what they are take it or leave it.

Comment: Alright I edited the question to give you the full picture of what the assignment is asking. Although it's no different from the information I initially provided. As you can see, I'm asked to write down the calculation process for finding the charging time given the parameters. Are you saying that it's not possible?

Comment: It’s a case situation... while Vin is 1 volt, the charging formula applies. When Vin reduces to (say) 0 volts the discharge formula applies. I see nothing in the question that implies you have to state anything more complex than what I’ve just said.

Comment: But I how can I use the charge formula to prove that the charging time is 0.00042 seconds (as shown in the QUCS simulator)?

Comment: There is no charge time. It takes infinitely long to charge a capacitor to 100.00000000000000000000.....% so you have to compromize and decide what you regard as fully charged. 5RC is generally well accepted and that takes 280 us. If this is good enough then QED.

Comment: So you're implying that to find the charging time (as per the question in the assignment), I should't use the amplitude and frequency as parameters and the 0.00042 seconds shown in the QUCS simulator was wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what your sim produced. Try it with different voltage levels and see that as a fraction of the Vin amplitude, amplitude does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers:

Note that the given circuit also acts as a low pass filter. If the input weren't a fundamental sine wave, then it will filter away the frequencies above \$\frac{1}{2\pi RC}\$ from the input, where RC is the time constant.